# Why does my Do While loop terminate?

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a server with multiple commands. Most commands work so far except that I want the server to send a warning to the client when the client writes an argument to the quit command. (I.E. quit xyz) and lets the user try again rather than exiting the server. Unfortunately the server quits whether the user types quit or quit arguments.

```
bool done = false;

do
{
    if(strcmp(cmd, "quit") == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(argument, "") != 0)
            strcpy(replyMsg, "504 Command not implemented for that parameter.\n");
        else
        {
            strcpy(replyMsg,"221 Service closing control connection.\n");
            done = true;
        }
    }
    while(strcmp(cmd, "quit") != 0 && done != true);
```

Comment: You are probably missing a }

Comment: There's a brace missing (closing brace of the do loop)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found out that my mistake was in the client side and the missing bracket is just a typo. I don't know how to properly close topics or should I just delete it?

Comment: Up to you. You might also fix the typo in your question and add an answer to your own own question in which you explain what was wrong on the client side. In any case, I believe my own answer about the fact checking `cmd` is redundant still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use:

```
...
}
while(!done);
```

There is no point checking `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop structure seems  missing brace before `while`
 to be wrong, or it is a typo. Check it first and lets see the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your test on the cmd in the while condition. Whenever he user chooses 'quit' it evaluates to false, so the whole expression is false  due to the conjunction and the loop exits